# How to provide sign up for a service from my website in iphone app?

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I have developed VoIP(SIP)Client for iPhone Customized with my company. 
I have added sign up button with my signpage URL but apple rejected my app.

Please tell how to implement App-in Purchase system. So user can sign up for my service.Add talk-time to sip account and other payment option.
All the things I have done in my website.

But apple not approve browsing my website within app like to sign up, add credit for talk-time, and other functional-ties.

Please help me, I would be greatly thankful to you:)

Gaurav Bhaskar.

Answer (score 0):

Apple's documentation, [on in-app purchases](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) is a great place to start. And [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178214/ios-in-app-purchase-sample-code) has a link to a book you can read that has sample code.

Google is your friend.